# Creating a macro/elisp function for HASH using calc

Tags: elisp-macros, calc

In my workflow, I need to do binary operations quite often. I am wondering if there is a clean way of creating macro/elisp-function to return value of following HASH function.

- Input 16bit hex number: ***NUM***
- Hash function return value = ***NUM[15] ^ NUM[13] ^ NUM[11] ^ ... ^ NUM[1]***
  (here ^ means XOR)
- For example:

  - If **NUM**(in hex)=0001, hash=0
  - if **NUM**(in hex)=8000, hash=1
  - if **NUM**(in hex)=000A, hash=0

Comment: This seems equivalent to `((NUM & 0x55) > 0)?1,0)` in C syntax. i.e. check if any of the odd bits are 1.

Comment: Hi Jiancho, not precisely. it's xor of all bits in odd position. Sorry, I'll edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In calc, you can perform this operation as follows:

- type your number to check (e.g. `16#32FE`)
- keep odd numbered bits: <kbd>16#AAAA b a</kbd>. This ands your number with 0xAAAA
- binary unpack with <kbd>b u</kbd>. This returns a list of active bits.
- count length of list with <kbd>V #</kbd>
- check for parity: <kbd>2%</kbd>

Turning this into a macro... (currently reading [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Programming.html)).

Comment: Thanks Juancho, this worked perfectly as I had expected. So many things yet to be explored in calc <3